# Tag ns1: repete em todas as outras tags (XML)

Tags: xml, xmldocument

Estou tentando fazer um XML mas a tag ns1 repete em todas no xml pronto, tem como resolver isto de um modo mais fácil?

**Exemplo do codigo:**

```
function TRPS.geraXML:TStrings;
var XMLDoc    : TXMLDocument;
ANode     : IXMLNode;
begin
try
   XMLDoc     := TXMLDocument.Create(Application);
   With XMLDoc do
   begin
     Active   := True;
     Version  := '1.0';
     Encoding := 'UTF-8';

     AddChild('ns1:ReqEnvioLoteRPS');
     DocumentElement.Attributes['xmlns:ns1']          := 'http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/lote';
     DocumentElement.Attributes['xmlns:tipos']        := 'http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/tp';
     DocumentElement.Attributes['xmlns:xsi']          := 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
     DocumentElement.Attributes['xsi:schemaLocation'] := 'http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/lote http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/xsd/ReqEnvioLoteRPS.xsd';

    ANode := DocumentElement;
    with ANode.addChild('Cabecalho') do
    begin
       AddChild('CodCidade').NodeValue            := Self.FPrestadorCidadeCodigoIBGE;
       AddChild('CPFCNPJRemetente').NodeValue     := Self.FPrestadorCPFCNPJ;
       AddChild('RazaoSocialRemetente').NodeValue := Self.FPrestadorRazaoSocial;
       AddChild('Transacao').NodeValue            := Self.FRPSTransacao;
       AddChild('DTInicio').NodeValue             := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',Self.FLoteDtInicio);
       AddChild('DTFim').NodeValue                := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',Self.FLoteDTFim);
       AddChild('QtdRPS').NodeValue               := Self.FLoteQtdeRPS;
       AddChild('ValorTotalServicos').NodeValue   := VirgulaPorPonto(FormatFloat('#0.00',Self.FLoteValorTotalServicos));
       AddChild('ValorTotalDeducoes').NodeValue   := VirgulaPorPonto(FormatFloat('#0.00',Self.FLoteValorTotalDeducoes));
       AddChild('Versao').NodeValue               := Self.LoteVersao;
       AddChild('MetodoEnvio').NodeValue          := Self.FLoteMetodoEnvio;
   end;
   Result := XMLDoc.XML;
finally
  FreeAndNil(XMLDoc);
end;
end;
```

**exemplo do XML entregue  tem a tag n1 em todo lugar**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   -<ns1:ReqEnvioLoteRPS xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/lote http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/xsd/ReqEnvioLoteRPS.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tipos="http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/tp" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost:8080/WsNFe2/lote">

   -<ns1:Cabecalho>
       <ns1:CodCidade>0</ns1:CodCidade>
       <ns1:CPFCNPJRemetente/>
       <ns1:RazaoSocialRemetente/>
       <ns1:Transacao/>
       <ns1:DTInicio>1899-12-30</ns1:DTInicio>
       <ns1:DTFim>1899-12-30</ns1:DTFim>
       <ns1:QtdRPS>0</ns1:QtdRPS>
       <ns1:ValorTotalServicos>0.00</ns1:ValorTotalServicos>
       <ns1:ValorTotalDeducoes>0.00</ns1:ValorTotalDeducoes>
       <ns1:Versao>0</ns1:Versao>
       <ns1:MetodoEnvio/>
       </ns1:Cabecalho>
   </ns1:ReqEnvioLoteRPS>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remova o :ns1 daqui:
DocumentElement.Attributes['xmlns:ns1'] := 
E daqui:
AddChild('ns1:ReqEnvioLoteRPS').
Como você está baseando seu xml em um schema, pode ser que seu framework ainda gere o xml com este indicador de namespace. Não é errado o que você quer fazer, mas seria interessante manter o ns1, já que ele indica a qual xml schema o complex type pertence. Esta é uma boa prática, já que pode acontecer de em um mesmo xml haver dois ou mais complex types, que inclusive podem conflitar. E sem a indicação da origem, a interpretação do seu xml fica prejudicada.
Dê uma olhada neste link para melhor emais completa explicação:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp